# Android and Room: inserting one-to-one objects

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying something in principle very simple, but I can't figure out properly:

I have two entities:

The `CategoryEntity`:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "categories",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = JobEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["jobId"],
            childColumns = ["categoryId"]
        )
    ],
    indices = [Index("categoryName", unique = true)]
)
data class CategoryEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryId") val categoryId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryName") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categorySlug") val slug: String,
)
```

And the `JobEntity`:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "jobs",
    indices = [Index("jobId", unique = true), Index("categoryId", unique = false)]
)
data class JobEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "jobId") val jobId: Long = 0,
    @Embedded val category: CategoryEntity,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url") val url: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "company_logo") val companyLogoUrl: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "company_name") val companyName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_type") val jobType: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publication_date") val publicationDate: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "candidate_required_location") val relocation: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salary") val salary: String?
)
```

A job can have ONE and ONLY ONE category, so it's a one-to-one relationship.

I'm fetching the data from a remote server, and the first thing I want to do is create a `CategoryEntity` from the `categoryName` JSON field that I receive in the network response.

The data that I receive in the network response:

```
@Serializable
data class Job(
    val url: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    @SerialName("company_name")
    val companyName: String,
    @SerialName("category_name")
    val categoryName: String,
    val tags: String? = null,
    val location: String,
    @SerialName("pub_date")
    val pubDate: String
)
```

In order to do this, these are the steps I'm following:

```
            // FIRST I create a `CategoryEntity` with the `categoryName`
            val categoryEntity = CategoryEntity(
                name = jobFromNetworkResponse.categoryName,
                slug = jobFromNetworkResponse.categoryName
            )

            // SECOND I Insert the category in the DB
            val categoryId = categoryLocalDataSource.insertCategory(categoryEntity)

            // THIRD I Convert the network response data object to my entity object
            val jobEntity = jobFromNetworkResponse.toEntity(categoryEntity)

            // FOURTH I insert the entity object into the DB
            localDataSource.insertJob(jobEntity)
```

However, following such procedure, I'm always getting the following in my `CategoriesDao` object, before inserting any job at all:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY[787])
```

```
@Dao
interface CategoriesDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertCategory(category: CategoryEntity): Long
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I defined the relationships wrong? Or is it maybe because I'm explicitly setting the `jobId` and `categoryId` to 0 and having the `autoIncrement = true`?

### Edit

I've tried this, and I'm still getting the same message:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "jobs",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = CategoryEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["categoryId"],
            childColumns = ["categoryId"]
        )
    ],
    indices = [Index("jobId", unique = true), Index("categoryId", unique = true)]
)
data class JobEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "jobId") val jobId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryId") val categoryId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url") val url: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "company_logo") val companyLogoUrl: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "company_name") val companyName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_type") val jobType: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publication_date") val publicationDate: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "candidate_required_location") val relocation: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salary") val salary: String?
)
```

Comment: Unsure about why the exception is occurring, but you can certainly debug root cause. Try attaching debugger at this point
https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/7c6846d6c4175a54cb2f6a2cd1624a799fad72c1/room/room-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/util/DBUtil.kt#L121

Comment: @hardik9850 it never stops there

Comment: The FKEY is saying that you MUST insert the job first as it is the parent of the Category. Either category first or have the FKEY defined in the job with the Category as the parent, then Category before Job.

Comment: @MikeT let me update my response with the latest modifications

Comment: Did you remove the FKEY definition from the Category as well as adding the FKEY to the Job?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments the original issue was that a Category was defined as having a Job as a parent. Thus a Category could not added with it's parent.

- Like life a baby cannot be born (excluding artificial methods) without a parent or parents.

So if you want to insert a Category before a Job then you would need to make the Category the parent to the Job. i.e. removing the Foreign Key definition from the Category and add a Foreign Key definition to the Job.

**However**, it should be noted that a Foreign Key definition DOES NOT determine/create a relationship instead it is a CONSTRAINT (Rule) that enforces Referential Integrity (children must have a parent). They are not required.

Assuming that you want the Category to be inserted first and specify a foreign key to enforce the referential integrity then the following cut down version (as used in the demo below, so less code for brevity and convenience) of the entities could be used:-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "jobs",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = CategoryEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["categoryId"],
            childColumns = ["categoryId"]
        )
    ]
    /*,
    indices = [Index("jobId", unique = true), Index("categoryId", unique = true)]
     JobId being the Primary Key is already a unique index so unecessary for index on the JobId
     unique index on category not really necessary, also restricts solid one to one
        it will enforce that a job cannot have the same category as another job, which seems to
        be overly restrictive (as such commented out).
     */
)
data class JobEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "jobId") val jobId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryId") val categoryId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url") val url: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "company_logo") val companyLogoUrl: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "company_name") val companyName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_type") val jobType: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publication_date") val publicationDate: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "candidate_required_location") val relocation: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salary") val salary: String?
)
@Entity(
    tableName = "categories"
    /*,
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = JobEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["jobId"],
            childColumns = ["categoryId"]
        )
    ],
     */
    ,indices = [Index("categoryName", unique = true)]
)
data class CategoryEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryId") val categoryId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryName") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categorySlug") val slug: String,
)
```

- i.e. the FKEY has been moved to the job.
- some comments

It is highly likely that you will want to get a Job with it's Category, from the Database (one or many). So a POJO for this purpose:-

```
/* POJO for handling relationship between job and category i.e. Job with its category */
data class JobWithItsCategory(
    @Embedded
    val jobEntity: JobEntity,
    @Relation(
        entity = CategoryEntity::class, parentColumn = "categoryId", entityColumn = "categoryId"
    )
    val categoryEntity: CategoryEntity
)
```

It very much appears that you want the retrieval of a **Job** as the basis for inserting data, but the Job does not include all of the information to be stored.

It appears that you retrieve all the data for both the category and job and it is available from the outset. As such the flow could be far simpler albeit undertaken by a more complex process.

That is you could have a single function to both insert the CategoryEntity and if successful then insert the JobEntity.

Such a function should react to/detect an already existing Category as a Foreign Key constraint cannot be circumvented. Try/Catch processing is not really considered ideal. As such a means of detecting an existing Category could circumvent Try/Catch. As an example, which will be demonstrated, consider:-

```
@Query("SELECT coalesce(max(categoryId),-1)  FROM categories WHERE categoryName=:categoryName")
    fun getCategoryId(categoryName: String): Long
```

- This will return the id of the Category if it exists, else -1.
- Obviously this will be in an `@Dao` annotated interface

As the POJO for retrieving a Job with it's Category another `@Query` that could be useful is:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM jobs")
fun getAllJobsWithTheirCategory(): List<JobWithItsCategory>
```

- again in an `@Dao` interface.

So back to the function. As the function will be accessing the database a number of times (see if the Category exists, if not then insert The Category and then if all is OK insert the Job with the inserted Category's id applied) then it should be undertaken in a single transaction. The functionality will not be an query or an insert but a mixture. So there is no direct annotation. However, Room will not wrap a transaction around a function if it thinks it will not access the database. As such Room needs to be told that the database is being accessed. Using `@Transaction` and `@Query("")` does this.

The function will be driven by a Job and also some other parameters;

- companyLogoUrl: String? = null,
- jobType: String?,
- salary: String,
- categorySlug: String,

Just in case a Job can use and existing Category a boolean parameter to either disallow or allow.

The function, defined in an `@Dao` interface could be:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun insertJobAndCategoryAllInOneFromAJob(
    job: Job,
    companyLogoUrl: String? = null,
    jobType: String?,
    salary: String,
    categorySlug: String,
    allowUseOfExistingCategory: Boolean = false
): Int {
    var resultOfCategoryInsert: Long=-1L
    var resultOfJobInsert: Long = resultOfCategoryInsert
    val categoryId = getCategoryId(job.categoryName)
    if (categoryId < 1) {
        resultOfCategoryInsert = insert(CategoryEntity(0L,job.categoryName,categorySlug))
    }
    if (allowUseOfExistingCategory && categoryId > 0) resultOfCategoryInsert = categoryId
    if (resultOfCategoryInsert > 0) {
        resultOfJobInsert = insert(
            JobEntity(
                0L,
                resultOfCategoryInsert,
                job.title,
                job.url,
                job.description,
                companyLogoUrl,
                job.companyName,
                jobType,
                job.pubDate,
                job.location,
                salary
            )
        )
    }
    if(resultOfCategoryInsert <= 0) return -9
    return resultOfJobInsert.toInt()
}
```

As it utilises other Room annotated functions (for the inserts) a single `@Dao` interface has been used. In it's entirety **AllDAOs** is:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(jobEntity: JobEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(categoryEntity: CategoryEntity): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM jobs")
    fun getAllJobsWithTheirCategory(): List<JobWithItsCategory>

    @Query("SELECT coalesce(max(categoryId),-1)  FROM categories WHERE categoryName=:categoryName")
    fun getCategoryId(categoryName: String): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    fun insertJobAndCategoryAllInOneFromAJob(
        job: Job,
        companyLogoUrl: String? = null,
        jobType: String?,
        salary: String,
        categorySlug: String,
        allowUseOfExistingCategory: Boolean = false
    ): Int {
        var resultOfCategoryInsert: Long=-1L
        var resultOfJobInsert: Long = resultOfCategoryInsert
        val categoryId = getCategoryId(job.categoryName)
        if (categoryId < 1) {
            resultOfCategoryInsert = insert(CategoryEntity(0L,job.categoryName,categorySlug))
        }
        if (allowUseOfExistingCategory && categoryId > 0) resultOfCategoryInsert = categoryId
        if (resultOfCategoryInsert > 0) {
            resultOfJobInsert = insert(
                JobEntity(
                    0L,
                    resultOfCategoryInsert,
                    job.title,
                    job.url,
                    job.description,
                    companyLogoUrl,
                    job.companyName,
                    jobType,
                    job.pubDate,
                    job.location,
                    salary
                )
            )
        }
        if(resultOfCategoryInsert <= 0) return -9
        return resultOfJobInsert.toInt()
    }
}
```

To actually demonstrate use of the above an `@Database` annotated abstract class:-

```
@Database(entities = [JobEntity::class,CategoryEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* For DEMO */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as  TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- **Note** for brevity and convenience the demo will use the main thread and thus suspend has not been used. Obviously adjustments for MVVM should be made if adapting this.

At this stage all that required Room wise exists. So now some Activity code to actually utilise the code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        /* Prepare Jobs to load */
        val j1 = Job("urlj1","J1","blah1","ACME Inc","CAT1",null,"London","2023-10-01")
        val j2 = Job("urlj2","J2","blah2","CMEA Inc","CAT2",null,"Paris","2023-10-02")
        val j3 = Job("urlj3","J3","blah3","MEAC Inc","CAT3",null,"Berlin","2023-10-03")
        val j4 = Job("urlj4","J4","blah4","EACM Inc","CAT1",null,"Texas","2023-10-04")

        /* Insert J1 logging issues if any */
        val j1Result = dao.insertJobAndCategoryAllInOneFromAJob(j1,"j1LOGOURL","TYPE1","50,000","catslugforj1",false)
        if (j1Result < 1) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Ooops job ${j1.title} not inserted. Code = ${j1Result} (if -9 then due to category not being inserted!)")
        }
        /* Insert J2 logging issues if any */
        val j2Result = dao.insertJobAndCategoryAllInOneFromAJob(j2,"j2LOGOURL","TYPE2","60,000","catslugforj2",false)
        if (j2Result < 1) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Ooops job ${j2.title} not inserted. Code = ${j2Result} (if -9 then due to category not being inserted!)")
        }
        /* Insert J3 logging issues if any */
        val j3Result = dao.insertJobAndCategoryAllInOneFromAJob(j3,"j3LOGOURL","TYPE3","70,000","catslugforj3",false)
        if (j3Result < 1) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Ooops job ${j3.title} not inserted. Code = ${j3Result} (if -9 then due to category not being inserted!)")
        }
        /* Insert J4 logging issues if any */
        /*!!!!!!!!!! WILL FAIL AS CATEGORY CAT1 EXISTS (but handled without an exception) !!!!!!!!!!*/
        val j4Result = dao.insertJobAndCategoryAllInOneFromAJob(j4,"j4LOGOURL","TYPE4","70,000","catslugforj4",false)
        if (j4Result < 1) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Ooops job ${j4.title} not inserted. Code = ${j4Result} (if -9 then due to category not being inserted!)")
        }
        /* Insert J4 logging issues if any  !!!!!!!!!! BUT THIS TIME ALLOW USE OF CAT1 !!!!!!!!!!*/
        val j4Retry = dao.insertJobAndCategoryAllInOneFromAJob(j4,"j4LOGOURL","TYPE4","70,000","catslugforj4",true)
        if (j4Retry < 1) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Ooops job ${j4.title} not inserted. Code = ${j4Retry} (if -9 then due to category not being inserted!)")
        }
        /* Retrieve the Data from the database getting each job with it's related category - write data the the log */ 
        for (j in dao.getAllJobsWithTheirCategory()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Job is ${j.jobEntity.title} .... Cat is ${j.categoryEntity.name} with slug ${j.categoryEntity.slug} and CATID ${j.categoryEntity.categoryId}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run after installing the App (the above is not really designed to be rerun) then the log shows:-

2023-09-02 07:35:25.601 D/DBINFO: Ooops job J4 not inserted. Code = -9 (if -9 then due to category not being inserted!)

2023-09-02 07:35:25.616 D/DBINFO: Job is J1 .... Cat is CAT1 with slug catslugforj1 and CATID 1
2023-09-02 07:35:25.616 D/DBINFO: Job is J2 .... Cat is CAT2 with slug catslugforj2 and CATID 2
2023-09-02 07:35:25.616 D/DBINFO: Job is J3 .... Cat is CAT3 with slug catslugforj3 and CATID 3
2023-09-02 07:35:25.616 D/DBINFO: Job is J4 .... Cat is CAT1 with slug catslugforj1 and CATID 1

- The first line indicates that the first attempt at adding Job J4 failed as the Category could not be inserted as it was found to already exist.
- That is the only issue encountered. As such the second attempt to insert Job J4 worked as **`true`** was specified for the `allowUseOfExistingCategory` value.
- The subsequent 4 lines show that J1-J4 were added and that the correct relationship between Job and Category exists (J4 was allowed to use CAT1)

App Inspection confirms the above, showing:-

[image]

and

[image]